# IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $; nested exception is com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException

Tags: spring-boot, http-post, postman, post-parameter

I'm doing a post request in SpringBoot and testing it with postman, but when I pass the body in Postman and try to read it in my application, it throws the error.
This is the method in Spring:

```
@PostMapping(path=PathConstants.START_ACTION)
    public String start(@PathVariable String processDefinitionId, @RequestBody(required=false) String params){

if(params!=null) {
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                Map<String,Object> pvar = gson.fromJson(params, Map.class);
                System.out.println(pvar);           
            } 
}
```

In Postman I pass params this way:

[image]

I specified in the header the content-type as `application/json`.
But then, if I pass my params using "Param" tab

[image]

it works. But I need to pass them as body and not params. Where is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Method 1 :

Header `Content-Type` is `application-json`. So Spring try to construct your `json` into a `LinkedHashMap`.

Now, try this...

```
@PostMapping(path=PathConstants.START_ACTION)
    public String start(@PathVariable String processDefinitionId, @RequestBody(required=false) Map<String, Object> bodyObject){

if(MapUtils.isNotEmpty(bodyObject)) {
              Map<String,Object> pvar = bodyObject;
}
```

instead of

```
@PostMapping(path=PathConstants.START_ACTION)
    public String start(@PathVariable String processDefinitionId, @RequestBody(required=false) String params){

if(params!=null) {
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                Map<String,Object> pvar = gson.fromJson(params, Map.class);
                System.out.println(pvar);           
            } 
}
```

and pass `header` the `content-type` as `application/json`. this will work..

> Method 2 ::

Now, if you still want to use your own old signature method like this ..

```
 @PostMapping(path=PathConstants.START_ACTION)
        public String start(@PathVariable String processDefinitionId, @RequestBody(required=false) String params){}
```

then in `header` the `content-type` as `text/plain`. then your older method will work also..